# filtering /0 (division by 0) value in Report Studio 10.2

Tags: filter, cognos, divide-by-zero, cognos-10

So I have a Rave Chart that is pulling in /0 and I can't for the life of me figure out how to filter them out. In a crosstab you are able to set what those values look like but in a rave chart I don't have that luxury. If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what have you tried?  Seems to me like you should be able to put a filter into your query for this.

Comment: @Andrew I have tried doing just that. Making the prompt = null, <> null, is null, if statements. I have tried everything I can think of but still not doing anything for me.

Answer (score 0):

Based on `a/b`.
I'd try something like this:
`where
(case when b = 0 then 0 
else a/b )
<> 0`

Or, possibly (this may be over-simplifying)
`where b <> 0`.

Comment: I haven't tried a case statement but I did try where b <> 0